# How can I fix: 'KeyError [x] not found in axis' when filtering dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, filtering

I am trying to filter my dataframe based on IQR for a few selected features. The code I use is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Load data
df = pd.read_csv("dataframe.csv")
features = df.loc[:, ('col1, col2, col3, col4, col5')]
 
print("Old Shape: ", df.shape)

def filtering(column_name):
    print(column_name)
    Q1 = np.percentile(df[column_name], 25,
                   interpolation = 'midpoint')
 
    Q3 = np.percentile(df[column_name], 75,
                   interpolation = 'midpoint')
    IQR = Q3 - Q1
 
    # Upper bound
    upper = np.where(df[column_name] >= (Q3+1.5*IQR))
    # Lower bound
    lower = np.where(df[column_name] <= (Q1-1.5*IQR))
    
    ''' Removing the Outliers '''
    df.drop(upper[0], inplace = True)
    df.drop(lower[0], inplace = True)
    print("New Shape: ", df.shape)
    print('==== done ====')

for col in features.columns:
    filtering(col)
```

The error (on line 28, df.drop(lower[0], inplace=True):

> KeyError: '[14] not found in axis'

The KeyError is caused by the fact that an index is already dropped because it is an outlier in one of the features, after which it is detected again. Since it is already dropped, this index cannot be found. I am however unsure how it is detected as an outlier after already being dropped. Therefore I am unaware how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Can you put an example of you dataframe data and a desidered ouput?

Comment: Sadly I am unable to provide my dataframe, I will attempt to explain my goal and dataframe. 
My dataframe has 283 rows and 40 columns, I want to filter outliers by calculating the Q1, Q3 and IQR as is shown in my post.
after calculating Q1, Q3 and IQR 'upper' and 'lower' are defined. These are both arrays with indices of the rows that need to be dropped, the goal is to drop all the indices from upper and lower.
The error is caused by the fact that a row has already been dropped but is still 'detected' as an upper or lower boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rethinking my approach, I have come up with a solution. I'll post my new approach here:

```
indices = []
def outlier_indices(column_name):
    Q1 = np.percentile(df[column_name], 25, interpolation = 'midpoint')
    Q3 = np.percentile(df[column_name], 75, interpolation = 'midpoint')
    IQR = Q3 - Q1
 
    # Upper bound
    upper = np.where(df[column_name].tolist() >= (Q3+1.5*IQR))[0].tolist()
    # Lower bound
    lower = np.where(df[column_name].tolist() <= (Q1-1.5*IQR))[0].tolist()
    indices.extend(upper)
    indices.extend(lower)

for col in features.columns:
    outlier_indices(col)

indices = set(indices)
df.drop(indices, inplace=True)
```

I have tackled the issue of getting duplicate indices by creating a list of indices and using set to remove the duplicate indices, which was then used to drop the outliers.

Answer (score 1):

Without the dataframe and line in which the error occurs its not that clear what happens

But in case you just want your script to run you could wrap it with a try/except block - like so:

```
try:
    # Your code
except KeyError:
    # Do what you want to do in case a KeyError occurs e.g. log something or print something
```

Comment: Thank you Chris, the KeyError is caused by the fact that an index is already dropped because it is an outlier in one of the features, after which it is detected again. Since it is already dropped, this index cannot be found.
I am however unsure how it is detected as an outlier after already being dropped.